# Rails: do non-ActiveRecord models need to include ActiveModel::Serializers, or just respond to #as_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

Using Rails 3.2, I'm working on an API backed model (not ActiveRecord). I want to be able to call `to_json` on this model in Rails controllers. After reading through a bunch of the ActiveModel docs I'm still not clear on one thing:

Given a model like this:

```
class MyModel
  attr_accessor :id, :name
  def initialize(data)
    @id = data[:id]
    @name = data[:name]
  end

  def as_json
    {id: @id, name: @name}
  end
end
```

Should this work as expected, or do I also need to include `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON`? I'm having a hard time figuring out where the `as_json` / `to_json` methods are normally defined and when Rails calls which ones automatically in different circumstances...

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 5):

Yes this does work, however not quote as you've written in.

When you render json in a controller using

```
def action
  render :json => @my_model
end
```

Then Rails will automatically call `to_json` on your object and as long as you've defined `to_json` this will work as expected.

If your controller uses the Rails 3 content negotiation shenanigans, ie.

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def action
    respond_with(@my_model)
  end
```

Then you will need to override `as_json` on your class, but the method signature requires an optional hash of options to be compatible with ActiveSupport so in this case you want

```
def as_json(options={})
  ...
end
```

Alternatively If you include `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON` into your Class and your class supports the `attributes` method that returns a hash of attrs and their values - then you'll get `as_json` for free - but without the control of the resultant structure that you have if you just override the method by hand.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the "Alternatively If you include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON into your Class and your class supports the attributes method that returns a hash of attrs and their values" that was key for me implementing a PORO with using AR Serializers.